# Indent paragraph following heading to match heading's indentation

Tags: microsoft-word

I want MS Word to indent a paragraph to the indentation of the heading immediately before it.

I know I can select having the paragraph style to be based on the previous paragraph's style, but I don't want to create a paragraph style for every heading style.  Creating styles will mean any changes later to the text paragraph style will have to be done on each of them; I won't be able to easily select all text except headings, etc.  I want a paragraph's text indentation to automatically match the preceding text's, even when the preceding text is a heading.

Can this be done?

Comment: How many heading styles do you use in one document?  Creating associated paragraph styles (a one-time effort), would be the typical way to do it, and that's the mechanism that uses the native Word design.

Comment: "I see" said the blind carpenter as he picked up his hammer and saw.

Comment: @fixer1234 Creating styles will mean any changes later (to the text paragraph style) will have to be done on each of them, and I won't be able to easily select all text except headings etc. As for `native Word design` - I'm looking for something even more _native_ - having a paragraph's text's indentation be automatically as the preceding text's _even when the preceding text is a heading_. (Edited to include "indentation".)

Comment: " I want a paragraph's text indentation to automatically match the preceding text's, even when the preceding text is a heading" - if I understand it strictly, then you'll just have all paragraphs with the same indentation in your whole document. Anyway, there is no easy way for that, either you use different styles, or the other option is to use macro to make the indentation from time to time.

Comment: If you don't want to change each indented text style separately, use a common base style for your 'text' styles (e.g. the Normal style). The 'text' styles do not differ from the base style, only the indent is different. The you only need to update the base style and the change is automatically reflected within all 'text' styles.

Comment: @0xA3 Thanks. I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I meant - every paragraph besides headings. Headings should keep their indentation.

Comment: @0xA3 - that should be the "answer" to this question. still have to create 2 styles per heading level (e.g., Header-1, Text-1) BUT all the "Text" styles can be based on a Common "Text" style (Normal being a suggested option).